# sequelize association On or ON

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Dears I have model order has association with OrderHasWarranty model

So OrderHasWarranty has 2 foreign key, I need Sequelize to check the include for both these foreign key (without using where condition)

so I used below associations in order model

```
Order.hasOne(models.OrderHasWarranty,{foreignKey:"orderId"});
Order.hasOne(models.OrderHasWarranty,{foreignKey:"warrantyFromOrderId"});
```

the raw query giving me :

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_has_warranties` AS `OrderHasWarranty` 
ON `Order`.`id` = `OrderHasWarranty`.`warrantyFromOrderId`
WHERE `Order`.`id` = '25459';
```

basically what i need is to convert the below query using association

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_has_warranties` 
AS `OrderHasWarranty` ON `Order`.`id` = `OrderHasWarranty`.`warrantyFromOrderId` 
OR `Order`.`id` = `OrderHasWarranty`.`orderId`   WHERE `Order`.`id` = '25459';
```

SO I need to use OR condition in associations, I tried using hasMany but no luck

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could get exactly what you are looking for, but I'm pretty sure that making the following changes could produce the desired result for you:

Add an alias to relations (you could choose some more appropriate)

```
Order.hasOne(models.OrderHasWarranty,{as: "warranty1", foreignKey:"orderId"});
Order.hasOne(models.OrderHasWarranty,{as: "warranty2", foreignKey:"warrantyFromOrderId"});
```

Then, you can include both of them in your search, like this:

```
Order.find({
  where: {
    id: 25459
  },
  include: ['warranty1', 'warranty2']
}).then(...).catch(...);
```

This would produce something like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_has_warranties` AS `warranty1` 
  ON `Order`.`id` = `OrderHasWarranty`.`orderId`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_has_warranties` AS `warranty2` 
  ON `Order`.`id` = `OrderHasWarranty`.`warrantyFromOrderId`
WHERE `Order`.`id` = '25459'
```

**EDIT:**
The error you are reporting might be caused by using the `hasOne` method to declare the association. The [Sequelize Doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#hasone) says:

> Even though it is called a HasOne association, for most 1:1 relations you usually want the BelongsTo association since BelongsTo will add the foreignKey on the source where hasOne will add on the target.

So, by adding also the `belongsTo` association, like this:

```
OrderHasWarranty.belongsTo(models.Order, {as: "warranty1", foreignKey:"orderId"});
OrderHasWarranty.belongsTo(models.Order, {as: "warranty2", foreignKey:"warrantyFromOrderId"});
```

your error should be resolved.

Comment: thank you dear, so i did below changes per ur comment 

                Order.hasOne(models.OrderHasWarranty,{as: "parentOrder", foreignKey:"orderId"});
                Order.hasOne(models.OrderHasWarranty,{as: "childOrder", foreignKey:"warrantyFromOrderId"});

and am getting this error now 

OrderHasWarranty (orderId) is not associated to Order!

Comment: this is my include : ["parentOrder","childOrder"] 
so am getting a new error 

Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.

Comment: Strange, the documentation reports that "You can also include by alias name by specifying a string that matches the association alias". What version of Sequelize are you using?

Comment: (Sequelize [Node: 6.9.1, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 3.30.4])

Comment: CLI version 3.9.1

Comment: My bad. The code I wrote works fine with [Sequelize 4.x](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#eager-loading). When working with [Sequelize v3.x](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading), you have to always declare the model to include. Something like this should work `include: [{model: OrderHasWarranty, as: 'warranty1'}, {model: OrderHasWarranty, as: 'warranty2'}]`.

Comment: i added (hasOne) in Order model and (belongsTo) in OrderHasWarranty model using the same alias, then i did the include using ur last comment, i got the same error again : 
Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.   --- please help :(

Comment: It's a very strange error. I have version 4.33.4 and it works just fine. You can't upgrade the module to the latest version, right?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give any other advice :(

Comment: sorry for the silly question :( how can i update Sequelize :$

Comment: If you use npm, `npm update sequelize` should do. ;)

Comment: nothing happened !!  cosnole :  npm update sequelize --save
console : sequelize --version

output : Sequelize [Node: 6.9.1, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 3.31.2]

same version